# Как вернуть максимальный id-шник в mysqli?

Tags: mysqli, php

Такой вариант не срабатывает. `var_dump($max)` возвращает NULL.

```
if ($result = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table1` WHERE `testrow1`=? OR `testrow2`=? OR `testrow3`=? OR `testrow4`=?")) {
    $result->bind_param("iiii", $usid, $usid, $usid, $usid);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($max);
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: Запрос теоретически правильный, проверь лучше его на бд, с реальными данными, возможно, что запрос нечего не возвращает

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Возможно, ошибка в том, что вопросительные знаки надо заключить в скобки.

```
"SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table1` WHERE `testrow1`='?' OR `testrow2`='?' OR `testrow3`='?' OR `testrow4`='?'"
```

Выполните данный запрос непосредственно в базе данных...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить данные из подготовленного выражения в mysqli, необходимо использовать метод `fetch()`

И, разумеется, запрос в принципе должен находить хоть одну строку, которая попадает под условие WHERE.

Кстати, вместо mysqli рекомендую использовать PDO. Кода выходит в два раза меньше

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table1` WHERE `testrow1`=? OR `testrow2`=? OR `testrow3`=? OR `testrow4`=?"));
$stmt->execute([$usid, $usid, $usid, $usid]);
$max = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если идут в порядке возрастания, то можно так: `mysqli_insert_id();`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```